# how to know the component rendering condition in react js

Tags: reactjs, routes, components, rendering

I have one component which is rendering as child as well or user can navigate to that component directly from menu of UI. I am facing one issue now is, if that component as child then its working fine but when I click upon menu to navigate directly then my getDerivedStateFromProps() function is throwing an error as

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Below is my code. It will work fine if I send a data from parent component to this component and render it from parent component.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.data.length)// this line is throwing an error when I directly come to this component from menu {
      const data = props.data;
      return { custData : data };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

How can I check the condition that not to execute above logic if I am coming to this component directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can double-check like this :

```
if (props.data && props.data.length)
```

Comment: ohh!! it is so simple but still missed it. Thanks a lot for quick help. Answer Accepted

Comment: @Nilesh, Glad to know, it helped

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the data exists

```
 if (props?.data)
```